# how to setup nuxt-socket-io auth on nuxt.config.js properly?

Tags: authentication, socket.io, nuxt.js

My plan is to send the token to the server. I could do this script inside of the `page.vue` (and it's working fine):

```
mounted() {
  this.socket = this.$nuxtSocket({
    channel: "/",
    auth: {
      token: 'abc'
    }
  })
} // socket.handshake.auth.token = abc
```

But I need the options on the `nuxt.config.js,` here's my attempt :

```
io: {
  sockets: [{
    url: 'http://localhost:3000',
    auth: {
      token: 'abc'
    },
  }]
}, // socket.handshake.auth.token = undefined
```

Any help are appreciated!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry if my question is unclear, anyway I solve it using built-in RuntimeConfig, and call it in page.vue. I'm not sure if it safe, but it's kinda solve my problem.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).